# How to generate STL from vertices?

Tags: dictionary, 3d, java-3d

I have a dictionnary containing veritces and normals of a 3D object as follow:

```
{
    "nbVertices": 1550,
    "nbFaces": 1245,
    "polySize": 4,
    "vertices": {...},
    "faces": {...},
    "normals": {...},
    "uvs": {...},
    "tangents": {...},
    "colors": null
}
```

Lengths:

`vertices` is a list of 3 times `nbVertices`

`faces` is a list of indeces of 4 times `nbFaces`

`normals` is a list of 3 times `nbVertices`

How can I convert this to an STL file?

I tried to group the vertices 3 by 3xyz to make triangles and format it as ASCII STL with no luck, I cannot figure out how the list of vertices is sorted

Answer (score 0):

The term `"polySize": 4` is the number of edges of the polygons. so we do not deal with triangles, but with 4-sided polygons.

I took the indeces 4 by 4 (4 indeces per face)
for each face, took the 4 vertices of the indeces above and the corresponding normal

An STL with 4-sided polygons is possible, but not compatible with all softwares, so I divided each 4-sided polygons on the diagonal to make 2 triangles